# Woocommerce | Composite Products & PrettyPhoto

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, prettyphoto

I ran into an odd issue using Woocommerce and [Composite Products](http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/)

When creating a product, you can choose products with variations and variation photos. In my build I have 4 products, each with several variations. The issue is when you select a new product, it loads the new lot of variations and photos via an AJAX call. In doing so, it breaks the ability for the photo to open in PrettyPhoto and when clicking on the photo it opens in a new window. This breaks the usability of the site and resets the customers options.

If the photo is already open, it works fine.

Clarity - Images that load via AJAX do not open in prettyPhoto.

What I am looking for is a bit of help to find the trigger I need to refresh prettyPhoto. I have searched around to no avail.

Likewise, woo is aware of the bug but has not committed to updating the plugin and resolving the issue.

You can see an example of the issue here (just select a head and click its thumbnail) - http://rip.bldsvr.com/shop/single-color-builder/

Comment: The best is that you use Chrome Inspector or Firebug plus searching inside the plugins' files to track down the issue. If you can't find a solution, at least you'd be able to add valuable info to the question.

Comment: I've looked through the plugin and the console and am not finding much of anything to go off of.

The main issue is not that it is broken somewhere, it is that I need to refresh PrettyPhoto after the AJAX event but I am not seeing what is actually making it all work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to add to get this working. I'm not 100% sure if this is the best fix, but it does seem to make everything work. Below is the default WooCommerce function for loading prettyPhoto and its theme.

Add `data-rel="prettyPhoto"` to your bto-product-image.php file (in the composite plugin folder) on line 12.

Then add the following to your scripts file (whatever file you are calling scripts from):

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function(){

// Lightbox
$("a.zoom").prettyPhoto({
    hook: 'data-rel',
    social_tools: false,
    theme: 'pp_woocommerce',
    horizontal_padding: 20,
    opacity: 0.8,
    deeplinking: false
});
$("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    hook: 'data-rel',
    social_tools: false,
    theme: 'pp_woocommerce',
    horizontal_padding: 20,
    opacity: 0.8,
    deeplinking: false
});

});
```